# How To read/iterate through a Datastream in Python

Tags: python-2.7, spark-streaming, data-stream

I have a stream created at port 9999 of my computer.
     [image]

I have to implement DGIM Algorithm on it.
However I am not able to read the bits in the Data stream one by one.
Below is my code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
import math
sc = SparkContext("local[2]", "NetworkWordCount")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
```

when I use the following command I am able to print the stream in batches:

```
lines.pprint()
ssc.start()             # Start the computation
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

[image]

But when I try to print each bit it gives an error:

```
for l in lines.iter_lines():
   print l
ssc.start()             # Start the computation
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

[image: DataStream error]

**Can someone tell me how can I read each bit from the stream so that I could 
 implement the algorithm on it?**

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code:

```
 streams.foreachRDD(lambda c: function(c))
 function(c):
    c.collect()
```

This makes an rdd out of each stream and the function collects all the streams